# how to fix my php session , because my login page doesnt login but it confirm details

Tags: php, session, authentication

My php script session is messed up , and my login page doesnt echo any erros meaning it was confirmed but my index page pushed back to the login page

i have tried different things but i dont know whatelse to do

this is the session.php code

```
session_start();

require '../sqlconnect.php';

$sessions = $_SESSION['token'];

if (!isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
    # code...
    header("Location: login.php");
}else{

    $all_details = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE token = '$_SESSION['token']'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($all_details)){

      $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_details);
      $id = $results['id'];
      $token = $results['token'];
      $email = $results['email'];
      $first_name = $results['first_name'];
      $is_admin = $results['is_admin'];
      $last_name = $results['last_name'];
      $matric_no = $results['matric_no'];
      $department = $results['department'];
      $level = $results['level'];
      $verified = $results['is_verified'];
      $age = $results['age'];
      $image_dir = $results['image_dir'];
      $gender = $results['gender'];

      // echo $username;
      }
}
```

and this is my index php code

```
 require 'session.php';
    require '../sqlconnect.php';
    require 'nav.inc.php';
    require 'navbar.inc.php';

    $errors = '';
    $success = '';
    $message = '';
```

and here is my login code

```
// require 'session.php';
session_start();
require '../sqlconnect.php';

$message = '';
$matric = '';

if (isset($_GET['enter'])) {
    # code...
    $message .= '<div class="uk-alert-success" uk-alert>
                            <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a>
                            <p class="black-text"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> '.$_GET['enter'].'</p>
                        </div>' ;
}


if (isset($_REQUEST['login'])) {
    # code...
    $matric = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['matric_no']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_REQUEST['password']);

    if (empty($matric)) {
        # code...
        $message .= '<div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert>
                            <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a>
                            <p class="black-text"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Matric Number Field is empty</p>
                        </div>';
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        # code...
        $message .= '<div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert>
                            <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a>
                            <p class="black-text"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Password Field is empty</p>
                        </div>';
    }
    if (!empty($matric) and !empty($password)) {
        # code...
        $confirm_query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM students WHERE matric_no = '$matric' and password = '$password' ");

        if (mysqli_num_rows($confirm_query) >= 1) {
            # code...
            $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($confirm_query);
            $_SESSION['token'] = $data['token'];
            $date_joined = $data['date_joined'];
            $updated_on = $data['updated_on'];

            if( $date_joined == $updated_on ){

                header("Location: changepass.php");

            }else{
                header("Location: index.php");
            }


        }else{
            $message .= '<div class="uk-alert-danger" uk-alert>
                            <a class="uk-alert-close" uk-close></a>
                            <p class="black-text">Login Credentials are Incorrect</p>
                        </div>';
        }
    }
}

require 'nav.inc.php';
```

this is just bouncing back to the login page everytime i login

Comment: Add `exit;` after your `header` calls.

Comment: this did not work

Comment: i was trying to debug that's why

Comment: The only reason `header("Location: login.php");` would be called is if `$_SESSION['token']` is not set and we can therefore conclude that `$_SESSION['token']` is not being set correctly. Or, the compiler never reaches the section where it is set.

Comment: can you help me fix it ? that's why i'm here